# how to enlarge an image view within the view which is animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to enlarge the size of an `UIImageView` which is inside a view.
Now the problem is I am showing this view with animation and it's becoming larger from small in size however the image is not enlarging. To make this `UIImageView` larger I am writing the same code which I wrote for view; that is

```
self.alertView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 235, 190);

self.alertImgView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 150);
```

and also i want to show this image view in between of this view that is not happening either. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this :-

```
[self.alertImgView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this as well but its not making any difference. Image view is showing on the same place. Its not even changes the size. Please share your views.